# Convert a raw TwoTuple to TwoTuple<A,B> in a wrong way but didn't get any warning（Java Generics）

Tags: java, generics

Enviroment： Java SE 7，Eclipse 4.2 
There r the codes :

code 1:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
public class Tuple {
    static TwoTuple<String, Integer> f() {
        return tuple("hi", 47);
    }
    static TwoTuple f2(){
        return tuple(new ByteArrayOutputStream(), 47);
    }
    public static <A,B> TwoTuple<A,B> tuple(A a ,B b) {
        return new TwoTuple<A, B>(a, b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoTuple<String, Integer> tt = f();
        TwoTuple<Boolean, Integer> tt2 = f2(); //  There is a wrong 
        System.out.println(tt);
        System.out.println(tt2);
    }
}
```

code 2:

```
public class TwoTuple<A,B> {
    private final A a ;
    private final B b ;
    public TwoTuple(A f , B s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        a= f;
        b=s;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "a : " +a+ " ; b : "+b;
    }
}
```

I made a mistake (  TwoTuple tt2 = f2()  )purposely,

but the codes can run  and compiler didn't think that is a mistake，why?

Comment: so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your mistake only warrants an IDE warning for unchecked conversion (<Object, Object> to <A,B>). If you disabled the warning/hints for this, nothing will happen. The compiler should state that you do have an unchecked conversion though.

Comment: @Sionnach733 sorry,my english isn't well, so it's difficult for me to describe the question clearly. My problem is why can a raw TwoTuple convert to TwoTuple<Boolean, Integer> with an unchecked conversion and it can run without any exception because I replaced f2() with f() before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler accepts this without errors (but not without warnings) since the `f2()` method is returning a raw `TwoTuple`, and you are performing an unchecked conversion to `TwoTuple<Boolean, Integer>`.

If you change the `f2()` method to a type-safe signature as below, you will get an error:

```
static TwoTuple<ByteArrayOutputStream, Integer> f2() {
    return tuple(new ByteArrayOutputStream(), 47);
}
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer ! Could u tell me why compiler accepts a raw TwoTuple convert to TowTuple<Boolean,Integer>.I replaced f2() with f() before,So the important thing is "a raw"  (sorry, my english isn't well).

Comment: @Sisox: It pretty much has to accept raw conversions, since otherwise a lot of legacy code (before 1.5) would be unusable together with code using generics.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't  describe the question clearly. I want to know why a raw TwoTuple convert to TwoTuple<Boolean, Integer> with an unchecked conversion by default.That seems to be a default setting,because I didn't change any setting.

Comment: @Sisox. I don't understand what you mean. What were you expecting to happen? I'm not quite sure what kind of settings you are referring to.

Comment: I expect that IDE tells me that I can't convert the object which generated by f2() to TwoTuple<Boolean,Integer>,because the object contains a ByteArrayOutputStream object,not Boolean.But my IDE didn't do that,which confused me. Thank u for ur patient !

Comment: I know that if I set f2() return a TwoTuple<ByteArrayOutputStream, Integer> object , IDE will warn me , but why can a raw TwoTuple object avoid that.

Comment: As soon as you assign the variable to a raw `TwoTuple`, you tell the compiler to disregard all other information. If the compiler used the parameterized information anyway you would run into all kinds of problems when combining your code with older code without generics.